# Masterplan's website has been compromised; please don't link to it

Tags: discussion

Masterplan's website has been compromised and is now directing to malicious sites. It looks like the domain expired in 2017 and has been picked up by some people with poor intentions, as tends to happen. It wouldn't be the first time they let the domain lapse but this time it might be gone for good.

Until such time it's restored (if ever), please do not link to the Masterplan domain.

This affects all sites in the `habitualindolence.net` domain. **Please don't visit that URL**; it's there only for your advisory. An archived version of the site is available on the Wayback Machine: [Masterplan @ June 2016](http://web.archive.org/web/20160720091339/http://masterplan.habitualindolence.net:80/).

The following posts have had Masterplan links removed, which may be restored after the domain is safe again:

- [Are Masterplan projects equivalent to adventures or campaigns?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25387/are-masterplan-projects-equivalent-to-adventures-or-campaigns/25397#25397) ^
- [What tools are available to create custom dungeon maps?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/what-tools-are-available-to-create-custom-dungeon-maps/5591#5591) *
- [Tree based tool to create dialog](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34816/tree-based-tool-to-create-dialog/34817#34817) **
- [Is there a Masterplan-like tool for 3.5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7951/is-there-a-masterplan-like-tool-for-3-5) ^
- [Are there any tools for creating a campaign from scratch?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7062/are-there-any-tools-for-creating-a-campaign-from-scratch/7065#7065)
- [Are there good tools for managing custom (homebrew) classes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/are-there-good-tools-for-managing-custom-homebrew-classes/15404#15404) *
- [Mapping software for dual monitors](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14736/mapping-software-for-dual-monitors/14740#14740) *

* Post also deleted, as it was solely a tool recommendation of Masterplan. If the tool's gone there's nothing to point people to.
** A section of the post pointing to Masterplan has been deleted.
^ Pointing to the Web Archive page.

Comment: Yeah I got pinged on the edit. Good to know!

Comment: May want to star the Oracle post in chat (for visibility)

Comment: Maybe we could change the links to their saves on the Wayback Machine, if there's any, and keep the posts up if they were useful?

Comment: @Sava Good idea. I've done that with two of them.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[What tools are available to create custom dungeon maps?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/what-tools-are-available-to-create-custom-dungeon-maps/5591?noredirect=1#comment337897_5591) Has a second answer that links to masterplan that should be deleted

Comment: Thank you very much. It's been removed now.